# Create an output document from Android App

Tags: android, pdf, rtf, doc

I have an android app where I will be capturing various information in different forms and storing into the SQL lite database for tracking/viewing purposes. I want to give the option of exporting the information into a RTF/PDF/Doc and give the option of sending it thru email.

I looked at various similar questions posted here earlier but didnt get a definitive answer. I saw the Android PDF Writer library http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/ but this seems very basic. I considered iText but I think there would be issues with licensing if in future I want to sell this app..

Basically I want to define a template document with a structure that will be copied and content added to it based on what the user wants to export...

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted some elegant solution where I can store a template in the assets folder and replace whatever I want to create the output document. Finally I went with html. I created a html template and put it into the assets folder. After that it was as simple as read assets, read db, do string.replaceall and write the output html and email it out.....

Comment: same problem for me. are you fix the problem?how to make my report as pdf?

Comment: There are multiple options for PDF. From API Level 19, Android natively supports creating PDF documents. You can refer the android documentation for the same. Another option is iText. With iText, you need to be careful about the licensing aspects.

Comment: and Thank you so much for valuable explanation. i going to try.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice.org's Universal Network Objects (UNO) interface to programmatically generate MS-Word compatible documents (*.doc), as well as corresponding PDF documents.

its basically java so it should work on android too.

Comment: Thanks for your response... Is it a web api? I dont want the content to be sent out for document creation...

Comment: it is a web api but i am sure it can be used otherwise too. i will try to get a link verifying that if possible.
also here is a brief explanation of the API
http://openofficejava.blogspot.in/2009/05/openofficeorg-api.html

Comment: UNO is not a web api, but it is likely to be too heavy for you to want to use on Android devices.  Also it's pretty hard to code to.  Docmosis has a cloud-based generation but you do have to send your data out over https.  It might be very hard to do this in multiple formats from Android itself.